# Filtering for NULL on a joined table

Tags: postgresql

I have this query:

```
select t1.l_id, coalesce(t2.o_id,0) from t1 left join t2  using(l_id);
```

which gives me a result, with `0` in the second column. However, when I put a `where` on the column, it gives me no results:

```
select t1.l_id, coalesce(t2.o_id,0) from t1 left join t2  using(l_id) 
    where t2.o_id = null;
```

How can I select records that have no joined record?

Comment: Comparisons to `null` are always false by definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
WHERE t2.o_id IS NULL;
```

instead of:

```
WHERE t2.o_id = NULL;
```

If `t2.o_id` is `NULL` then the second predicate evaluates to `NULL` not true as one might expect. This is the so-called [**three-valued logic**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) of SQL.